# Use QR decomposition to find LS decomposition, where S is orthonormal and L is a lower triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Assuming that we have a black box that can find the QR decomposition of a matrix $A$, how can we use this black box to find a decomposition $A=LS$ where $L$ is a lower triangular matrix and $S$ is an orthonormal matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $A^T=QR$, then $A=R^TQ^T$.